# Using "get" in affirmative and question sentences

Tags: questions, present-continuous, present-simple, causative-get

Sometimes I come across the sentences with *get* in strange (for me) place. For example:

> *Does it get boring wearing the same clothes every day?*

Why *get* is here? Can I say different way?

One more example with affirmative sentence I don't understand the difference between:

> This question is likely to get closed.
>   This question is likely going to be closed

I'm wondering is there any difference and where should I use ***"get"*** such way in affirmative and question sentences?

Comment: Interchange **get** with **become**; they have the same meaning so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get

> intransitive verb
> 1b : to reach or enter into a certain condition

"Does wearing the same clothes every day enter into the condition of being boring?"

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, ***to get*** can mean ***to become***. Some of the most common verbs can be very flexible in their meaning. So:

> I **got** the measles.

That means that I contracted the disease, measles.

> I **got** bored waiting for the bus.

That means that I became bored while waiting for the bus.

> I've **got** to **go**, I'm expected at home.

That means that it's necessary that I leave - two means of *to go* in one clause - because people are waiting for me at home. In some dialects, in casual speech, it may even become:

> I **got** to **go**, I'm expected at home.